# Install additional .exe with Visual Studio Installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-installer

I am currently trying to work out how to install an additional .exe with my visual studio applicaiton. It works in General but it don't know how to check before the installation if the additional .exe is already installed.

I assume the best option is to check the registy for a similiar entry and then check the result as a condition for installation?

I search on the Target Maschine for the registry entry:

[image]

Then I put the result as a condition in the custom action where the exe is installed.

[image]

Is the return Value a Bool or a String?
Is my condition correct?

```
NOT WEBVIEW2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is BOOL.

Yes. Use  `NOT  <property of WebView2>`  eg. NOT WEBVIEW2

In addition, make sure the properties of WebView2:

REGKEY:

```
SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}
```

Property : `WEBVIEW2`

Comment: I did everything as you said and checked if it is already installed but it installs it anyways?

Comment: Never mind. I added the Property at the wrong place. Thank you for the Help!